# UPDATE sql column with highest value from another column

Tags: mysql

i'll try to make myself as clear as possible.

I've got two tables, one called Users the other called Users_status.

**Table Users**

```
column 1 : id (pk)
column 2 : status (fk)
```

**Table Users_status**

```
column 1 : user_id (fk)
column 2 : user_status (fk)
```

I want to make a cron that verifys that the column 2 of the table Users is up to date of the column 2 of the table Users_status
The table Users_status may have multiple times the user_id repeating, with the user_status incrementing, like this :

**Table Users_status**

```
user_id : 1
user_status : 1

user_id : 1
user_status : 2

user_id : 1
user_status : 3

user_id : 2
user_status : 1

user_id : 2
user_status : 2
```

I want with 1 request, to update the second column of the table Users ( status ) according to the latest (highest) user_status present in the table Users_status
I also want to not update rows that have already the good status ( same status as the table Users_status )

How can this be done? I've tried so many things, and when I tought that would work, it either just swapped the status from 1 to 2, and 2 to 1, or some MYSQL constraints errors happened.

I'd really be glad if someone could help me on that

Thanks,

Comment: specifically the HIGHEST Status, vs whatever the LAST status entered for a given user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join with a subquery for that

```
UPDATE users
JOIN (SELECT
         user_id,
         MAX(status) status
      FROM
         users_status
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) st
ON users.id = st.user_id
SET users.status = st.status
WHERE users.status < st.status
```

Comment: Thanks that perfectly did the job, I think I was missing the group by part, which I still don't really get why

Answer (score 0):

This query working for me :

```
 update users set status = case when id <> (select b.j from (select m.id j
 from users m join users_status n on m.id=n.user_id and m.status=n.user_status) b) then
 (select max(user_status) from  users_status group by user_id having 
 users_status.user_id=users.id)  
  else status END;
```